# Execute PHP after echo'ing to AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Let's I have this ajax call:

```
App.prototype.askServer= function(obj) {

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'php/ajax.php',
        data: {
            stuff: obj
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

And my ajax.php looking like this:

```
<?php

$stuff = $_POST['stuff'];

// execute curl that takes 1 second

echo $response

// parse $response through multiple loops and save into files and databases
// takes 5 seconds

?>
```

Will the ajax callback execute as soon as the PHP script `echo`'s something? Or will it wait for the whole PHP script to be executed? In other words: will my ajax callback be executed after 1 or 6 seconds?

The reason I'm asking is because I get a pretty large JSON from a `curl`. I want to return it to an ajax callback and after that, I want to take that data apart, save some stuff into a database, other data into a JSON file and so on. This takes a while but it's unnecessary for the client to wait for that.

Comment: The request will complete when the PHP page has finished processing and the server has returned its content. In other words, it would be 6 seconds + transport timing, given the timings in your example.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to close the connection early while PHP continues to execute the script.

You will need to define `ignore_user_abort(true);` in your PHP script and call `flush();` right after `echo $response;`
The script continue to execute, but the connection will be closed causing Ajax callback to execute.

Comment: sounded promising, didn't work though. Added `ignore_user_abort(true);` on top of my ajax.php and called `flush();` after the echo. The ajax callbacks still waited for the php script to finish

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split the processing. Just register the request from your user and process it later. There are several so called message queues or worker queues available for PHP. You might want to have a look at RabbitMQ